# output of cloning method in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, clone

```
     // Creating a new HashMap
     HashMap<Integer, String> hmap2 = new HashMap<Integer, String>(); 

     // cloning first HashMap in the second one
     hmap2=(HashMap)hmap.clone();
     //System.out.println("Cloned Map contains: "+hmap2); 
     String x = hmap.get(11);
     x = "aks";
     hmap.put(11, x);
     hmap.put(99, "kdkshkjshdk");

     System.out.println("Cloned Map contains: "+hmap); 
     System.out.println("Cloned Map contains: "+hmap2); 
  } 
}
```

Why the changes in the hmap are not getting refelcted in hmap2? This is a shallow copy and both hmap and hmap2 are pointing to same memory reference.
Please correct where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You are cloning the empty hmap to hmap2 and then setting the values in to hmap.

```
     // Creating a new HashMap

     HashMap<Integer, String> hmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

     HashMap<Integer, String> hmap2 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

   //System.out.println("Cloned Map contains: "+hmap2); 

     String x = hmap.get(11);

     x = "aks";

     hmap.put(11, x);

     hmap.put(99, "kdkshkjshdk");

     // cloning first HashMap in the second one

     hmap2=(HashMap)hmap.clone();



     System.out.println("Cloned Map contains: "+hmap); 
     System.out.println("Cloned Map contains: "+hmap2);
```